# What condition might cause Equities to rise, and corporate bond spreads to rise as well?

Tags: investing, economics

I was wondering about this earlier and I'm stumped.

Comment: Corporate bond spreads are a  measure of liquidity, risk, and the general economic/market condition.  Change in the spread isn't completely  linear so at times, there are periods of fluctuation in a wider long term cycle.  That might account for your observation.  My understanding of them is limited and therefore, I couldn't drill down in a micro economic sense and explain why it's happening now or at any other point in time.

Answer (score 1):

If interest rates are falling overall, this increases the general valuation of the stock and bond markets. If there is also some concern about economic weakness, and/or strong demand for Treasurys, this could increase corporate bond *spreads* because corporate yields may fall but not as much as Treasury yields.